# How to use Faktory with a ruby job and a python worker?

Tags: python, ruby, sidekiq

I want to use a ruby script to submit jobs to a faktory server (https://github.com/contribsys/faktory/wiki) to launch a python worker. 
Faktory should be perfect for that being language agnostic but the documentation covers only the ruby only (job and worker) or python only (job and worker) cases. Quickly, I have two questions:

- How to register the worker on the python side so that it is addressable from the ruby side?
- How to code correctly the ruby job (in particular, is the perform method required)?

Here is a minimal (not) working example.
First, the python worker file:

```
from faktory import Worker 
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def python_worker(var_int):
    print(var_int)

w = Worker(queues=['default'], concurrency=1)
w.register('PythonWorker', python_worker)
w.run()
```

Now the ruby file:

```
class RubyJob < ApplicationJob
    include Faktory::Job
    faktory_options retry: 5
    queue_as :default

  end
```

To call the job I use `RubyJob.perform_later(1)`.

Coming back to the two questions:

- Does the ruby job need a 'perform()' method?
- How do I tell the ruby job to require from faktory the 'PythonWorker'?

For the moment I need register the python worker as 'ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::FaktoryAdapter::JobWrapper'.

Maybe useful would be a minimal example of a ruby job and a python worker similar to the examples for ruby (https://github.com/contribsys/faktory/wiki/Getting-Started-Ruby) or python (https://www.mikeperham.com/2019/01/08/using-faktory-with-python/) only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ruby code doesn't need any jobs at all. The job is Python. The Ruby code just needs to create and send the job record to Faktory so the python worker can pick it up. In Ruby, you create a basic job using the plain old Faktory::Client API:

```rb
c = Faktory::Client.new
c.push('jobtype' => 'PythonWorker', 'args' => [1], 'queue' => 'default', 'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12))
```

Start Faktory, start a faktory_worker_python process and run that code in your Ruby app.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. As complementary question: I use ruby on rails, and need to submit the same job several times in one session. Is it better to each time create a new faktory client object 'c = Faktory::Client.net' or have an initializer and use the same (global) object several times?

Comment: Faktory::Client is not thread-safe so you should create it each time or use a pool of Clients, e.g. with the connection_pool gem. Don't use globals.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also had to add a job id to the push command. For instance c.push( 'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12), 'jobtype' => 'PythonWorker', 'args' => [1], 'queue' => 'default'). I am not sure it is 100% necessary, but without it did not work for me.